# Google Sheets API Python заполнение таблицы одним списком

Tags: python, алгоритм, парсер, google-spreadsheet

Ребят, вопрос по Google Sheets API, как выгрузить сразу список парсера, вместо того что бы просто записывать в таблицу по одному запросу?
Вот у меня есть пример функции которая записывает файлы в csv, можно ли сделать нечто подобное в Google Sheets?
Мне это нужно элементарно для экономии времени и денег, потому что я конечно могу вывести в таблицу значения вот таким вот образом:

```
                worksheet.update_cell(i, 1, name)
                worksheet.update_cell(i, 2, f'{DT.datetime.now():%d-%m-%Y}') 
                worksheet.update_cell(i, 3, '')
                worksheet.update_cell(i, 4, natural_price)
                worksheet.update_cell(i, 5, nal)
```

Но тогда 1 `update_cell` = 1 запросу, а это очень плохо.

Список формирую напрямую в функции которая выполняет парсинг, передаю его в качестве аргумента.

```
def save_goods(
        file_name: Union[str, Path],
        items: List[Tuple[str, str, str]],
        encoding='utf-8'
):
    df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=["Data",'Name','', 'Price', 'Nal'])
    df.to_csv(file_name, encoding=encoding)

#Запись в csv таблицу
```

---

```
def GoogleApi(
        items_spreadsheet: List[Tuple[str, str, str]],
        encoding='utf-8'
        ):
     sheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body = {
    'properties': {'title': 'Первый тестовый документ', 'locale': 'ru_RU'},
    'sheets': [{'properties': {'sheetType': 'GRID',
                               'sheetId': 0,
                               'title': 'Лист номер один',
                               'gridProperties': {'rowCount': 1500, 'columnCount': 15}}}]}).execute()

#Создание гугл таблицы
```

Вот весь код программы, если нужно:
https://dpaste.org/XQ8N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для передачи больших объемов данных подойдет метод [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate), надо только подготовить для него тело запроса:

```py
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    body = {
        'valueInputOption': 'RAW',
        'data': [{
            'range': 'Sheet2!B2',
            'values': [
                ["foo", 1, 10.0],
                ["bar", 12, 33.0],
                ["baz", 4, 57.8],
            ]
        }]
    }
    resp = sheet.values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SHEET_ID, body=body).execute()
```

Comment: А что такое `values`? Это данные которые вводятся?

Comment: Да, в `values` должны быть ваши данные - в коде просто пример.